# OpenLDAP editing userPassword attribute ACL

Tags: ldap, acl, openldap

I try to create user, which can read other users password. I try to edit ACL already present in openLDAP, so I wrote:

```
dn: olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcAccess
olcAccess: {1}to attrs=userPassword 
 by self write 
 by anonymous auth 
 by dn="cn=admin,dc=playground,dc=test,dc=local" write 
 by dn="cn=usermanager,ou=cloud,o=customer1,dc=playground,dc=test,dc=local" read 
 by * none
```

the only modification in above olcAccess ACL from my side is:

**by dn="cn=usermanager,ou=cloud,o=customer1,dc=playground,dc=test,dc=local" read**

After I do that (via ldapmodify) I loose ability to browse ldap tree as usermanager, but I can login, exmaple:

`ldapsearch -x -D "cn=usermanager,ou=cloud,o=customer1,dc=playground,dc=test,dc=local" -W -LLL`

returns: `No such object (32)`

`ldapwhoami -x -D "cn=usermanager,ou=cloud,o=customer1,dc=playground,dc=test,dc=local" -W -LLL`

returns: `dn:cn=usermanager,ou=cloud,o=customer1,dc=playground,dc=test,dc=local`

Question is: how to write this ACL to grant user `usermanager` rights to read other users password?

Comment: You posted the same ldapsearch query twice, the second one binds with `cn=admin,dc=playground,dc=test,dc=local` if understand correctly? (please edit your post)

Comment: first is ldapsearch second ldapwhoami, on top is ldif file content

Comment: Ah ok I didn't read correctly.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

```
dn: olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcAccess
olcAccess: {1}to attrs=userPassword 
 by self write 
 by anonymous auth 
 by dn="cn=admin,dc=playground,dc=test,dc=local" write  
 by dn="cn=usermanager,ou=cloud,o=customer1,dc=playground,dc=test,dc=local" read  
 by * none
```

if anyone wants to use that please write it manually instead of copy-paste as ldifs are terribly sensitive on whitespaces and line endings.

Comment: Most important: two or more whitespaces in front of "by", rest should not be too sensitive in this case.